# Rails controller params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot access the controller params hash as I expect. I understand it is a [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters) but no matter what I've tried I always run into this error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Here is controller method:

```
def cuisine
   @selection = params("name")  // or params(:name)
end
```

Here is routes.rb

```
get '/cuisine/:name', to: 'main#cuisine'
```

What I get in the view from `params` itself (`@selection`) is a hash..

```
{"controller"=>"main", "action"=>"cuisine", "name"=>"american"}
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as

```
 @selection = params["name"] # or @selection = params[:name]
```

`params("name")` is `params` method call with one argument, not a [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) method call. You need to use `Hash#[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use square brackets:

```
def cuisine
   @selection = params["name"]  # or params[:name]
end
```